# \sys_get_shell:nnN seems to strip newlines from shell output

Tags: listings, expl3, shell-escape

Goal: run a shell command and `\input` its output as LaTeX code.

See related: [How to protect \input shell command args with backslashes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/669968/how-to-protect-input-shell-command-args-with-backslashes/669983#669983)

When using expl3's `\sys_get_shell:nnN`, newlines from the shell output seem to be replaced with spaces.
This is a problem when using certain commands like `\begin{lstlisting}`, which discard any text on that line up to a newline character, then process all text on future lines up to `\end{lstlisting}`.

For example, the following produces warnings and ignores the `BOO` and `BAH`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[breaklines]BAH
Failed to run:
\end{lstlisting}
\begin{lstlisting}[breaklines]BOO
-bash: notACommand: command not found
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Warnings:

```
Package Listings Warning: Text dropped after begin of listing on input line 5.
Package Listings Warning: Text dropped after begin of listing on input line 8.
```

Output:

```
Failed to run:
-bash: notACommand: command not found
```

The following, using `\input`, works as expected, including newlines from the shell output:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\input{"|OUTPUT=`notACommand \\2\\\{\\3\\( 2>&1` && echo $OUTPUT || ( ( echo \\\\\\\\begin\\{lstlisting\\}\\[breaklines\\] && echo Failed to run: && echo \\\\\\\\end\\{lstlisting\\} ) && ( echo \\\\\\\\begin\\{lstlisting\\}\\[breaklines\\] && echo $OUTPUT && echo \\\\\\\\end\\{lstlisting\\} ) )"}

\end{document}
```

producing desired output:

```
Failed to run:
sh: notACommand: command not found
```

However, the seemingly-equivalent use of `\sys_get_shell:nnN` turns newlines from the shell output into spaces:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \someVarForShellOutput % declare this variable
\cs_new_protected:Nn \inputFromShellCall:n {
  \sys_get_shell:nnN { #1 } { \ExplSyntaxOff } \someVarForShellOutput % disable expl syntax when parsing shell output
  \tl_analysis_show:N \someVarForShellOutput % for debugging - we see that the newlines from shell output are now spaces
  \tl_use:N \someVarForShellOutput
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \inputFromShellCall:n { e } % Create \inputFromShellCall:e which expands its argument before invoking the shell
\ExplSyntaxOff

\ExplSyntaxOn
\inputFromShellCall:e { OUTPUT=`notACommand~ \c_backslash_str 2 \c_backslash_str \{ \c_backslash_str 3 \c_backslash_str (~2>&1`~&&~echo~$OUTPUT~||~(~(~echo~\c_backslash_str \c_backslash_str \c_backslash_str \c_backslash_str begin\{lstlisting\} \c_backslash_str [breaklines\c_backslash_str ]~&&~echo~Failed~to~run:~&&~echo~\c_backslash_str \c_backslash_str \c_backslash_str \c_backslash_str end\{lstlisting\}~)~&&~(~echo~\c_backslash_str \c_backslash_str \c_backslash_str \c_backslash_str begin\{lstlisting\}\c_backslash_str [breaklines\c_backslash_str ]~&&~echo~$OUTPUT~&&~echo~\c_backslash_str \c_backslash_str \c_backslash_str \c_backslash_str end\{lstlisting\}~)~) }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

The debugging `\tl_analysis_show:N` shows that the shell output is:

```
(|OUTPUT=`notACommand \2\\{\3\( 2>&1` && echo $OUTPUT || ( ( echo \\\\begin\{lstlisting\}\[breaklines\] && echo Failed to run: && echo \\\\end\{lstlisting\} ) && ( echo \\\\begin\{lstlisting\}\[breaklines\] && echo $OUTPUT && echo \\\\end\{lstlisting\} ) ))
The token list \someVarForShellOutput contains the tokens:
>  \begin (control sequence=macro:->\protect \begin  )
>  { (begin-group character {)
>  l (the letter l)
>  s (the letter s)
>  t (the letter t)
>  l (the letter l)
>  i (the letter i)
>  s (the letter s)
>  t (the letter t)
>  i (the letter i)
>  n (the letter n)
>  g (the letter g)
>  } (end-group character })
>  [ (the character [)
>  b (the letter b)
>  r (the letter r)
>  e (the letter e)
>  a (the letter a)
>  k (the letter k)
>  l (the letter l)
>  i (the letter i)
>  n (the letter n)
>  e (the letter e)
>  s (the letter s)
>  ] (the character ])
>    (blank space  )
>  F (the letter F)
>  a (the letter a)
>  i (the letter i)
>  l (the letter l)
>  e (the letter e)
>  d (the letter d)
...
```

Even though manually running the shell command

```
OUTPUT=`notACommand \2\\{\3\( 2>&1` && echo $OUTPUT || ( ( echo \\\\begin\{lstlisting\}\[breaklines\] && echo Failed to run: && echo \\\\end\{lstlisting\} ) && ( echo \\\\begin\{lstlisting\}\[breaklines\] && echo $OUTPUT && echo \\\\end\{lstlisting\} ) )
```

produces output with a newline before "Failed":

```
\begin{lstlisting}[breaklines]
Failed to run:
\end{lstlisting}
\begin{lstlisting}[breaklines]
sh: notACommand: command not found
\end{lstlisting}
```

https://mirror.mwt.me/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/interface3.pdf for `\sys_get_shell:nnN` states:

```
The ⟨shell command⟩ is converted to a string using \tl_to_str:n. Category codes may need to be set appropriately via the ⟨setup⟩ argument, which is run just before running the ⟨shell command⟩ (in a group).
```

`\tl_to_str:n` sounds like it applies to the input to the shell, but not the output, thus shouldn't be relevant here.
The category code setup here seems like it should be OK - I turn off expl3 syntax since `lstlisting` doesn't seem to work inside `\ExplSyntaxOn` (I haven't investigated why).

Edit: this can also be reproduced where the shell invocation site is not inside `expl3` syntax, so no category code setup should be required:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \someVarForShellOutput % declare this variable
\cs_new_protected:Nn \inputFromShellCall:n {
  \sys_get_shell:nnN { #1 } { } \someVarForShellOutput % disable expl syntax when parsing shell output
  \tl_analysis_show:N \someVarForShellOutput % for debugging - we see that the newlines from shell output are now spaces
  \tl_use:N \someVarForShellOutput
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \inputFromShellCall:n { e } % Create \inputFromShellCall:e which expands its argument before invoking the shell

\NewDocumentCommand{\simpleNameInputFromShellCall}{m} {
  \inputFromShellCall:e { #1 }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\simpleNameInputFromShellCall{ OUTPUT=`notACommand \\2\\\{\\3\\( 2>&1` && echo $OUTPUT || ( ( echo \\\\begin\{lstlisting\}\\[breaklines\\] && echo Failed to run: && echo \\\\end\{lstlisting\} ) && ( echo \\\\begin\{lstlisting\}\\[breaklines\\] && echo $OUTPUT && echo \\\\end\{lstlisting\} ) ) }

\end{document}
```

Why are the newlines in shell output getting turned into spaces by `\sys_get_shell:nnN`, and can this be prevented?

Second edit:

[How can I save shell output to a variable in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70854/how-can-i-save-shell-output-to-a-variable-in-latex) talks about how `\read` reads balanced lines and converts newlines to spaces.
It says "To avoid this, you set `\endlinechar` to -1.", but that turns newlines into <nothing>.

Setting `\endlinechar` in the `\sys_get_shell:nnN` setup arg to something visible like `\endlinechar=97` (which is `a`) successfully produces `a`s instead of newlines. But `\endlinechar=10` (the actual ascii code of the newline char) actually inserts newlines where they're present in the shell output, but seems to have the wrong category code for listlisting to recognize it.

I also tried manually modifying the catcode after setting the newlinechar:
`\sys_get_shell:nnN { #1 } { \endlinechar=10 \catcode\endlinechar=5 } \someVarForShellOutput`
to everything from 1 to 16, without success.
Setting it to 5 results in the newline getting replaced by a space - the same behavior without any shell setup code, which makes sense, since its default catcode (outside EXPL) seems to be 5: `\showthe\catcode\endlinechar`.

This language is painful lol, and I see no workaround, other than skipping `\sys_get_shell:nnN` and using `\input{"|..."}` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fundamentally you still need to understand how catcode in TeX works to understand what the expl3 functions are doing (for which TeXbook/TeX by topic helps).

In any case, the verbatim-like environments such as `listings` changes catcode while reading the content, while expl3 `sys_get_shell:n` tokenizes the whole content right after they're read, which makes it impossible to guarantee the correct behavior of `listings`.

(*) if you know exactly what catcodes are expected by `listings` and set those precise catcodes, it might be possible; nevertheless this implementation depends a lot on the internal implementation of `listings` environment.

In any case, one workaround is to get the **raw** content with `sys_get_shell` and tokenize it with `scantokens` (for which there's no expl3 wrapper at the moment (`\tl_rescan` and variants tokenize the whole thing at the start, which is not applicable here because of the same reason mentioned above), apart from `\tex_scantokens:D` which is not a "wrapper" at all)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}


\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{test.txt}
\begin{lstlisting}
line 1  !?%#\xyz
line 2
\end{lstlisting}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \someVarForShellOutput % declare this variable
\cs_new_protected:Nn \inputFromShellCall:n {
    \sys_get_shell:nnN { #1 } { \cctab_select:N \c_other_cctab \endlinechar=10~ } \someVarForShellOutput
    \scantokens \expandafter { \someVarForShellOutput }
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \inputFromShellCall:n { e } % Create \inputFromShellCall:e which expands its argument before invoking the shell

\NewDocumentCommand{\simpleNameInputFromShellCall}{m} {
  \inputFromShellCall:e { #1 }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\simpleNameInputFromShellCall{ cat test.txt }

\end{document}
```

Refer to [How can I read the whole file content verbatim into a (expl3) string variable?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/647304/how-can-i-read-the-whole-file-content-verbatim-into-a-expl3-string-variable/647305#647305) for explanation of the catcode change parts.

Comment: p/s. ● there's currently no "programming in expl3" tutorial, and the documentation is "not the best" at \*teaching\* the language. ([copy](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/669429/space-counting-in-expl3-is-strange/669468#comment1664134_669468)) ● don't blame the expl3 developers for the language quirks, they're all problems inherited from TeX that are unfixable without massive overhead. ([example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/670293/250119))

Comment: also there's never any token with catcode 5. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/349607/character-bytes-and-character-tokens-if-newlines-are-converted-to-spaces-then https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117906/use-of-everyeof-and-endlinechar-with-scantokens for some examples, and of course the books for the actual explanation.

Comment: Makes sense - adding on a programming interface (expl3) to a non-programming language (TeX) adds some nice features, but can't fix fundamental language problems. It also still requires the programmer to understand the underlying language. If I continue to want to try to mix programming and LaTeX, I'll keep the programming separate, or maybe try LuaTeX.

Comment: The wrappers for `\scantokens`  are `\tl_rescan:nn` and `\tl_(g)set_rescan:Nnn`

Comment: @JosephWright I know both of them, but these are not as powerful as scantokens because they tokenize the whole thing in one go. (edited answer to mention that)

Comment: @user202729 True, but my experience is that 99% of the time, if `\scantokens` looks like the answer then you are asking the wrong question ;)